# Error deploying shinyapp, package

Tags: r, shiny

Has anyone seen this error and know what to do about it? I've tried updating the shinyapps package, but it didn't fix the problem. I have version 0.10.2.1 of shiny, and 0.3.61 of shinyapps, rstudio version 0.98.1074

> Preparing to deploy application...Error: /v1/applications/?filter=account_id:18320&filter=name:nextword&count=100&offset=0 426 - shinyapps package out of date.
>
> To update visit: https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps
>
> Execution halted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the shinyapps package using devtools:

`devtools::install_github('rstudio/shinyapps')`

Since the shinyapps package only exists on GitHub (not on CRAN), using `update.packages()` will not update the shinyapps package.

Answer (score 0):

Alex, I think @kippandrew has the wrong syntax. You should be using:

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/shinyapps')
```

Let us know what worked.

P.S. On the [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/admin/#/dashboard) Dashboard, the Shiny team have detailed step by step how to get started. Getting shinyapps is Step 2.

For those getting started. Step 1 is to get yourself devtools.

```
install.packages('devtools')
```